# Codeigniter / Ecommerce Drill Down Menu with Active Record / MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, codeigniter, e-commerce

I am creating a custom ecommerce system for a client who sells custom grad gear. I have the following screen shot of my product layout...

[image: Ecom image]

I have the form on the right side of the page that has a max price, colors and materials. When you click the Update options it sends all the data via jquery's ajax function over to my codeigniter controller where i need to pull a new list of products with the options that they have selected and within the price range they have selected. I then pass the products array to a codeigniter view and return the view to the cart with the ajax success variable.

So I can get this working with just colors, or just materials, but my problem is figuring out how to pull a set of products that has all of the materials and options I need. I guess I just can't wrap my brain around the best way to do it. I thought about pulling a list with the correct colors, then a list with the correct materials, then a list with the correct pricing and then deleting duplicates in a merged array, but it just doesn't feel like thats the best way to do it.

This particular client only needs "color" and "material" as an option so my products table is set up to have the id of the color and the id of the material all in the products table. Then I have a colors and materials table with the id and the color or the id and the material.

What are you guys thoughts on the best way to do this? I'd like to use codeigniters active record to do the mysql stuff.

## ///// EDITS ///////////////////////////////////////

Here is an image of my product Tables:
[image: product tables]

Also, here is my jquery controlling the submit of data to the codeigniter controller:

```
//Filter Options Ajax
```

$('#updateOptions').click(function(event) {

```
//Prevent the default href action
event.preventDefault();

var filterOptions = $('#filterForm').serialize();

//Get the site url
var siteUrl = $('#siteUrl').val();

//Roll up the product listing div and show a loader
$('div.products').slideUp( 500, 'easeInExpo' );
$('div.loader').delay(500).fadeIn();

//Get a new list of products and repopulate the information
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: siteUrl + "category/filterProducts",
     data: { filterOptions: filterOptions },
     success: function(data) {
        $('div.loader').fadeOut(500);
        $('div.products').html(data).delay(500).slideDown( 500, 'easeOutExpo' );
     } 
});
```

});

Comment: We would need to know the database structure for all applicable elements in this question. For example, are price, color and so on relational or are they stored as something like a serialized array? Ideally all of it should be broken down into a straight shot query, if possible.

Comment: I have added an image of my product tables above. My problem is that when I choose say, red and blue for the colors and 12.00 for the max price, I am pulling results that are priced correctly, but all colors are in there because its like i'm writing it to say "pull all the products below 12.00, and also all the products that are red or blue". So its basically pulling all colors because the price matches.

What it should say is something more like "Pull all products of the correct price, THEN eliminate everything that is NOT red or blue, same for materials.

Comment: Also i'm going to have to do something about knowing how many colors and material options have been selected so i can loop through them. I wrote a big intricate while loop for it earlier and it didn't work. Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: You want the query to say pull where price is equal or less than 12 AND (color = red OR color = blue). definitely NOT eliminate after. It may work technically, but that's just not a good way to do things. You could GROUP by id to eliminate duplicates that have both colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
if ($min_price = $this->input->get_post('min_price')) {
    $this->db->where('price <', $min_price);
}
```

Then the url `prices.php?min_price=100` would add `WHERE price < 100` to your query.

For colors (I'm using `|` for a delimiter, but use what works for you):

```
if ($colors = $this->input->get_post('colors')) {
    $colors = explode($colors, '|');
    $this->db->where_in('color', $colors);
}
```

Then the url `prices.php?min_price=100&colors=red|blue` will add

```
WHERE price < 100 AND color IN ('red', 'blue')
```

If you are posting your colors using an array (checkboxes) try this:

```
if ($colors = $this->input->post('colors')) {
    $this->db->where_in('color', $colors);
} elseif ($colors = $this->input->get('colors')) {
    $colors = explode($colors, '|');
    $this->db->where_in('color', $colors);
}
```

This lets you use the url or the POST to add your colors, depending on how you're doing things.

Comment: I've figured out the pricing part, It's just that I need to pull the products by price, Then eliminate results that match the colors they picked and the materials they picked. That's whats getting me down.

Comment: OH WHERE_IN... i've used it before and totally forgot about it. I'm going to try it and I'll report back.

Comment: I have two arrays. like:

$colors = array(
     1 => 'red'
     1 => 'blue'
);

can i pass an array to the where_in function? I guess I could look this up on codeigniters docs but i'm already here. lol.

Comment: yeah: `where_in(string $column, array $values)`. In my code I use `explode()` which returns an array.

Comment: Ok, your idea is FOR SURE going to work, I just have to figure out this last problem. When I do:

$colors = array(3,6);
$this->db->where_in('color', $colors);

it works perfectly, but when i pass it my actual array, which outputs the EXACT same thing ( i tested it by print_r on it), it doesn't work...

$colors = implode(',',$colors);
$this->db->where_in('color', $colors);

Comment: Well, turns out I could just pass the $colors array straight to the where_in function and that fixed it 100%. Its working like a beast now. Thanks for the ideas and help!

Comment: np. The problem is the `implode()`, since that turns it into a string. `where_in()` expects an array.